# Import a function from JS to JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a JS file containing this code:

```
module.exports = function loadMyFun() {

    function activateSite($currentItem) {
        ...
    }
  ...
}
```

And I want to import it into a JSX file, I tried to do it like this but I doesn't work:

```
import MyNav from './MyNav.js';

const top = MyNav.activateSite();

    componentDidMount () {
        var self = this;
        MyNav.activateSite($(self));
    }
...
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: _MyNav.default.activateSite is not a function

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the code you provided is actually the module you are trying to load, then there are a few problems with that module.

You are exporting a constructor `loadMyFun`, which you are not calling/instantiating after importing it.

If you would instantiate your constructor like this `const myNav = new MyNav()` you would have a instance of your exported constructor.

To make your `activateSite` function work, you would have to assign it to the instance itself and move it out of the local scope of `loadMyFunc` by assigning it like this: `this.activateSite = function(){...}`

If you dont need any information wrapped around your `activateSite` function I would recommend you export an object with your functions instead of the `loadMyFun` approach.

```
//myModule.js
module.exports = {
    activateSite: function(){ ... }
}
//otherFile.js
import { activateSite } from './myModule.js' // With destructuring
activateSite()

import myModule from './myModule.js' // Without destructuring
myModule.activateSite()
```

Comment: "You are exporting a constructor loadMyFun" — It's a function. We can't tell if it is a constructor. There isn't enough code in it.

Comment: I was assuming it because he is trying to access the defined function inside. That would require `this`, or an object of all functions as a return value.

Answer (score 4):

`activateSite` is a variable that is **locally scoped** to the `loadMyFun` function.

It is not available outside the scope of `loadMyFun`.

It is not a property of the `loadMyFun` function object.

You cannot access it without rewriting the module.

e.g.

```
module.exports = function loadMyFun() {
};

module.exports.activeSite = function activateSite($currentItem) {
};
```